# playwright select button by next element

Tags: css, unit-testing, selector, playwright

```
<div class="mysel">
   <button class="btn"></button>
   <div class="iconName">James</div>
</div>
<div class="mysel">
   <button class="btn"></button>
   <div class="iconName">John</div>
</div>
```

I want to click the button by codition of James
so I try to use selector by this

```
 page.locator('button:right-of(:text("james")').click();
```

but fail
how I could choice the button by txt in the next div?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's not much context to work from here, and the `-of` selectors seem dependent on CSS/layout information I don't have, but selecting based on `.mysel`'s text works for your example:

```js
const playwright = require("playwright"); // ^1.28.1

const html = `
<div class="mysel">
  <button class="btn">GOT IT</button>
  <div class="iconName">James</div>
</div>
<div class="mysel">
  <button class="btn"></button>
  <div class="iconName">John</div>
</div>
`;

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await playwright.chromium.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setContent(html);
  const sel = '.mysel:has(:text("james")) button';
  console.log(await page.locator(sel).textContent()); // => GOT IT
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

`'.mysel:has(.iconName:text("james")) .btn'` is also possible in case there are other elements and you need to be more specific.